# hitTestPoint doesn't work when it's move

Tags: actionscript-3

I use the "localToGlobal" method detect for collision.I set the border points for all borders of an enemy and i have a collision.But it's doesn't work when its move.

Here is the pic about of issue.

https://s33.postimg.cc/6fuw14nb3/image.gif - work

https://s33.postimg.cc/cutwy04db/image.gif - doesn't work

Code

```
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;


import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

    var geriyonlev1:Number=+4;


var increment:Number = 0;    //amount the car moves each frame

var carRotation:Number = carMC.rotation;    //rotation of the car



var aracsag:Number = +5;

var aracsol:Number = -5;





var bPoint:Point = new Point(34,65);//right bottom corner

bPoint = dubageri1.localToGlobal(bPoint);



var cPoint:Point = new Point(-34,-40);//left top corner

cPoint = dubageri1.localToGlobal(cPoint);



var pxPoint:Point = new Point(-40,65);//left bottom corner

pxPoint = dubageri1.localToGlobal(pxPoint);



var orPoint:Point = new Point(27,-40);//right top corner

orPoint = dubageri1.localToGlobal(orPoint);









///*** HIT CONTROL EVENT *** \



stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,sssa);

function sssa(event:Event) {


    var zHit:Boolean = carMC.hitTestPoint(bPoint.x, bPoint.y, true);

    textbaba.text = zHit? "! HIT !": "NO HIT";

    if(zHit){

            //dubageri1.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }



    var cHit:Boolean = carMC.hitTestPoint(cPoint.x, cPoint.y, true);

    textbaba2.text = cHit? "! HIT !": "NO HIT";

    if(cHit){

            //dubageri1.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }



    var pxHit:Boolean = carMC.hitTestPoint(pxPoint.x, pxPoint.y, true);

    textbaba3.text = pxHit? "! HIT !": "NO HIT";

    if(pxHit){

            //dubageri1.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }



    var orHit:Boolean = carMC.hitTestPoint(orPoint.x, orPoint.y, true);

    textbaba4.text = orHit? "! HIT !": "NO HIT";

    if(orHit){

            //dubageri1.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }



    //carMC.x=mouseX;

    //carMC.y=mouseY;


}







stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ilkcikis);

function ilkcikis(event:Event) {


    if (geribas.yonler < -10) {

        geribas.bizimnumara = geribas.yonler;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,aracharekets);

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ilkcikis);

        trace("kalkti");



    }else if (geribas.yonler > +10) {

        geribas.bizimnumara = geribas.yonler;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,aracharekets);

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ilkcikis);

        trace("kalkti");

    }

}






///*** CAR CONTROL EVENT *** \




function aracharekets(event:Event) {


    if(geribas.yonler>9){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -10;

        carMC.x += aracsol;

    }

    if(geribas.yonler>15){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -13;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>21){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -16;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>27){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -19;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>33){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -22;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>39){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -25;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>45){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -28;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>51){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -31;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>57){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -34;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>63){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -37;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>69){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -40;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>75){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -43;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>81){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -46;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>85){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -49;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler>91){

        carMC.rotation += .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(3);

        carMC.rotation = -52;



    }









    ////////////// DUZ HAREKETLER



    if(geribas.yonler<-8){

        carMC.gotoAndStop(1);

        carMC.rotation = 0;

}   

if(geribas.yonler<8){

        carMC.gotoAndStop(1);

    carMC.rotation = 0;

}







    ////////////// EKSI HAREKETLER



    if(geribas.yonler<-9){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 10;

        carMC.x += aracsag;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-15){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 13;





    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-21){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 16;





    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-27){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 19;





    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-33){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 22;





    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-39){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 25;





    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-45){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 28;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-51){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 31;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-57){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 34;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-63){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 37;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-69){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 40;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-75){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 43;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-81){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 46;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-85){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 49;



    }

    if(geribas.yonler<-91){

        carMC.rotation -= .5*increment;

        carMC.gotoAndStop(2);

        carMC.rotation = 52;



    }





/// ENEMY MOVE DOWN



    dubageri1.y += geriyonlev1 +3;





}
```

Comment: Because you don't update your points and their global/stage coordinates remain the same, which is somewhere above the screen, I think? That's why they never hit - they above the screen, the car is on screen. You need to get the global/stage coordinates of these points every frame before you hit test them.

Comment: I put the point variables in to the event listener.Now it's fine.Thank you.